# Caffe Installation error: [error adding symbols: File in wrong format]

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, deep-learning, caffe

I am installing Caffe on Ubunutu 17.10. I am getting error during cmake compile:

```
[ 72%] Building CXX object 
src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/signal_handler.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object 
src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/upgrade_proto.cpp.o
[ 74%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_hl.so: error adding symbols: 
File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:2745: recipe for target 
'lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:267: recipe for target 
'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' 
failed
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

### output from cmake.. :

```
-- Boost version: 1.62.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/local/include, library: 
/usr/local/lib/libgflags.so)
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libglog.so)
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/bin/protoc
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine CXX configuration
-- Found lmdb    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/liblmdb.so)
-- Found LevelDB (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so)
-- Found Snappy  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so)
CMake Warning at cmake/Dependencies.cmake:82 (message):
  -- CUDA is not detected by cmake.  Building without it...
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (include)  
-- OpenCV found (/usr/share/OpenCV)
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatlas.so lapack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so
-- NumPy ver. 1.12.1 found (include: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include)
-- Boost version: 1.62.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
--
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   1.0.0
--   Git               :   1.0-87-g5c6a2905-dirty
--   System            :   Linux
--   C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/c++
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   ON
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   ON
--   CPU_ONLY          :   ON
--   USE_OPENCV        :   ON
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   ON
--   USE_LMDB          :   ON
--   USE_NCCL          :   OFF
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.62)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 3.0.0)
--   lmdb              :   Yes (ver. 0.9.70)
--   LevelDB           :   Yes (ver. 1.20)
--   Snappy            :   Yes (ver. ..)
--   OpenCV            :   Yes (ver. 3.1.0)
--   CUDA              :   No
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver. 2.7.14)
--   Libraries         :   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.14)
--   NumPy             :   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.1)
-- Documentaion:
--   Doxygen           :   No
--   config_file       :
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /home/caffe/build/install
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/caffe/build
```

### Makefile.config:

```
CPU_ONLY := 1
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

### CMakeLists.txt:

```
# ---[ Includes
set(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-D_FORCE_INLINES ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

### CMakeCache.txt:

BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-fPIC

If i try build caffe with make all command - get error:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
g++ -shared -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0 .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o .build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o .build_release/src/caffe/net.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.o.build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/dummy_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/reduction_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/neuron_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/elu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/recurrent_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lcn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/infogain_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/embed_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/spp_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/argmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/input_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/lstm_unit_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/batch_reindex_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/flatten_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/base_conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/batch_norm_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_deconv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/power_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/bias_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/hinge_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/parameter_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/tile_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/reshape_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/rnn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/log_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/split_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/scale_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/filter_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/lstm_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/crop_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/common.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adam_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/rmsprop_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adagrad_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/nesterov_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/internal_thread.o .build_release/src/caffe/parallel.o .build_release/src/caffe/blob.o .build_release/src/caffe/layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/data_transformer.o .build_release/src/caffe/syncedmem.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/math_functions.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/insert_splits.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/signal_handler.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/cudnn.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/hdf5.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/benchmark.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/io.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/im2col.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.o -Wl,-soname,libcaffe.so.1.0.0 -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib -pthread -fPIC -DCAFFE_VERSION=1.0.0 -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/hdf5/serial -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial -L.build_release/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_viz -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_serial_hl -lhdf5_serial -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so when searching for -lhdf5_serial_hl
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.a(H5LTanalyze.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `H5LTyyin' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:572: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I don't understand how to solve this error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Error `recompile with -fPIC` means that a **library you link with** (in your case - `libhdf5_serial_hl.a`) should be compiled with `-fPIC`. As for error `File in wrong format`, it usually means that a library architecture is incompatible with your needs. E.g. you build 32-bit program, but a library is 64-bit.

Comment: Thank so much! Both errors due to incorrect file libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0